# Prove that if $A$ is antisymmetrical and $n$ is odd, then it is not invertible.

Tags: linear-algebra

> $\mathcal{M}_n(\mathbb{R})$ is the set of squared matrices of order $n$.
>
> $\mathcal{S}_n(\mathbb{R})$ is the set of symmetrical matrices and >$\mathcal{A}_n(\mathbb{R})$ is the set of anti-symmetrical matrices.
>
> We consider the endormorphisms $f$ and $g$ on $\mathcal{M}_n(\mathbb{R})$ such that:
>
> $f(M) = \frac{1}{2}(M + ^t M)$ and $g(M) = \frac{1}{2}(M - ^t M)$
>
> 1. Writing $M$ as a linear combination of $f$ and $g$, show that $\mathcal{S}_n(\mathbb{R})$ and $\mathcal{A}_n(\mathbb{R})$ are complementary in $\mathcal{M}_n(\mathbb{R})$.
> 2. Deduce that $Imf = \mathcal{S}_n(\mathbb{R})$ and $Img = \mathcal{A}_n(\mathbb{R}) $
> 3. Determine a necessary and sufficient condition for the product $AB \in \mathcal{S}_n(\mathbb{R}) $
> 4. Prove that if $ A \in \mathcal{A}_n(\mathbb{R}) $ and $n$ is odd, then $A$ is not invertible.

---

1. From the expression of $f$ and $g$ we have: $M = f(M) + g(M)$.

I don't know how to show that $\mathcal{S}_n(\mathbb{R})$ and $\mathcal{A}_n(\mathbb{R})$ are complementary in $\mathcal{M}_n(\mathbb{R})$.

2. Knowing that: $\mathcal{S}_n(\mathbb{R}) \oplus \mathcal{A}_n(\mathbb{R}) = \mathcal{M}_n(\mathbb{R})$, I don't know how to deduce $Imf = \mathcal{S}_n(\mathbb{R})$ and $Img = \mathcal{A}_n(\mathbb{R}) $
3. Let $A,B \in \mathcal{S}_n(\mathbb{R}) $,

$AB = ^tA. ^tB = ^t(BA)$

If $AB = BA$, we'll have $AB = ^t(AB)$ which proves that $AB \in \mathcal{S}_n(\mathbb{R}) $

We will get the same result if we started from $AB = BA$

4. I don't see how to use the fact that $n$ is odd to prove that $A$ is not invertible.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Well, you quickly get $\det A = - \det A$ so...

Comment: @lulu Could you elaborate more please? How am I going to use $n$ is odd?

Comment: Well, we have $A^T=-A$, yes?  Thus $\det A = \det A^T=(-1)^n\det A$.

Comment: @lulu Ah! I see now, thank you. Could please look at my other questions? Thank you.

Comment: Since $M = f(M) + g(M)$, then $\mathcal S_n(\mathbb R) + A_n(\mathbb R) = M_n(\mathbb R)$. What do you know about the intersection $S_n(\mathbb R) \cap A_n(\mathbb R)?$

Comment: @JuanDiegoRojas I don't understand how you past from $M = f(M) + g(M)$ to $\mathcal{S}_n(\mathbb{R}) + \mathcal{M}_n(\mathbb{R}) = \mathcal{M}_n(\mathbb{R})$. 

Although, I am asked to prove that in the next question. 

The intersection is the null matrix.

Comment: Note that $f(M)$ is a symmetric matrix and $g(M)$ is an antisymmetric matrix..

Comment: @JuanDiegoRojas. I see, so deducing that $Imf = \mathcal{S}_n(\mathbb{R})$ and $Img = \mathcal{A}_n(\mathbb{R}) $ is going to be from the fact the linear combination is unique?

Comment: Well, if $M$ is already symmetric, $f(M)=M$. So, question 2 is pretty straightforward.

Comment: @JuanDiegoRojas Thank you for your help. =)